# OpenCL development platform?

Tags: opencl

I am developing OpenCL code on a linux cluster through SSH - 
are there any tools that would make this process easier, i.e.
something like NVIDIA Parallel Nsight for OpenCL ?

Answer (score 0):

No there is no such tool, though you might try developing your code using ordinary computer and post production versions there..

Answer (score 0):

If the computer where you perform development is also running Linux, you can easily mount a remote folder as local. In a Gnome environment, open Nautilus (the file manager), click File => Connect to server, chose SSH, fill the required parameters, and you have a remote folder as local.

You can then use any IDE you want to develop code, and maybe perform simple runs, tests and debugs if the OpenCL tools (compiler, debugger) you're using remotely are also installed locally. However, To compile and properly run the code on the cluster, you need to use the ssh client on the command line.